# Creation of objects and delegation much slower than one big method?

Tags: java, performance

The question is related with memory and primary performance.
Last few days I was reflecting on this topic, it is not something I needed to use, just curious.
I created a simple example:

1) One class that uses no delegation and has no inner classes:

```
public class NoInnerClass {
public void theMethod(int times){
    for(int i=0; i<times; i++){
        System.out.println("No Inner hello: " + i);
    }
}
}
```

2) One class that calls four inner classes. The last one does the same as NoInnerClass in theMethod method

```
public class InnerMain {
    private Inner1 inner1 = new Inner1();

    public void theMethod(int times){
        inner1.doIt(times);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class Inner4 {
public void theMethod(int times){
    for(int i=0; i<times; i++){
        System.out.println("Inner 4 hello: " + i);
    }
}
}
```

I measured the time difference in milliseconds between this two types of calls.
The difference was not that big - a bit more than one millisecond. But what if we have much more complex inner objects and more delegating calls, we would for sure have bigger difference.

So the questions are:

- Will the difference in time and amount of memory used between two approaches increase dramatically
- If yes, is there any articles about this (I couldn't find much)
- Or maybe todays JVM is so smart, that we shouldn't think about it

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: That: "*Or maybe todays JVM is so smart, that we shouldn't think about it*"... The obvious optimisation here will be method inlining, which should compile the two codes to essentially the same instructions... BTW the difference you find may be a  measurement issue rather than an actual performance difference.

Comment: The difference is average number of several tries. And thanks for reminding about inline code :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference that you find (a bit more than one millisecond) could very much be an artifact of your benchmarking technique. Moreover, it is meaningless to talk of a millisecond without knowing the time of the entire run: if the time is in hundreds of milliseconds, then the difference is small; if the time is itself in single-digit milliseconds, the difference is significant; if the time is in seconds, then the difference is a measurement error.

Modern JVMs optimized virtual calls to such levels of efficiency that any difference that you could see would be very hard to measure. It is much better to concentrate on making the code as clear as possible using all the coding techniques available to you, including the virtual call, and start optimizing only when your profiler tells you that it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you in all you say. The code is just an example.
But what if we have bigger objects and more delegation...

Comment: @user3188414 Size of the objects does not matter. Moreover, increasing the size of your objects' methods would reduce the share of the overhead. If your program does not have performance problems, optimizing it is a waste of time. If your program does have performance problems, it's almost a guarantee that the overhead of virtual calls is not going to make the top-100 list of things that slow down your program.

Comment: That is the answer that I wanted to hear :) Thank you.

Comment: @user3188414 You are welcome! If you are satisfied with the answer, consider accepting it by clicking the grey checkmark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a new badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The difference will be negligible for the vast majority of programs. Yes, a method invocation might take a couple dozen cpu cycles, but for most methods, that is far less than the invoked method does. In your case, you're doing I/O. Even if it is just a console, repainting that console will be far more expensive than invoking a method.

Moreover, the JVM is quite good at inlining method calls, which reduces method invocation overhead even further (leaving only a type check for an overridable method).

I recommend not to worry about the performance of language constructs until you have evidence of an actual performance problem in your code.

PS: A millisecond for 4 method invocations is not plausible. It's probably an artifact of your benchmarking approach. (How accurate is the timer? Are you sure the benchmark thread hasn't been peempted to give the CPU to another program? Are you seing a garbage collection pause? Did the just in time compiler run?)

Oh, and about memory: The difference are 4 objects on the heap. Of course it depends on what these objects are (if each references a huge array it might matter), but small objects take like 16 bytes of memory. Surely you can spare 4 * 16 = 64 bytes of memory? Or are you inquiring about the increased stack size? That too is negligible.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.
In this topic I wanted to put out the question - is creating objects and method invocation much slower than inline code.
And the code is pretty simple, I wrote it here just as an example. The main thing is - what if we have in real application bigger objects and more delegation...